# MATLAB implementation of erf(x)

Tags: taylor-expansion, matlab, error-function

I have implemented erf(x) using its Taylor expansion in Matlab. But even after repeated attempts to correct it, it shows wrong answer for x>1. I am not able to understand why it is so.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function ret = erfEval(x,b)
# b denotes how much error is to be compensated for the x value
n = 26;
c = ones(n+1,1);  # Coefficient array
c(1) = 1;
for i=2:n+1
  c(i)=c(i-1)*(2*i-3)/((2*i-1)*(i-1)); % Calculating the coefficients to be multiplied
end

# ret denotes the return value
ret = zeros(length(x),1);
for i = 1:13
  ret = ret + (-1)^(i-1)*c(i)*(x.^(2*i-1));
end

if b>1
for i = 14:21
  ret = ret + (-1)^(i-1)*c(i)*(x.^(2*i-1));
end
end

if b>3
for i = 22:n+1
  ret = ret + (-1)^(i-1)*c(i)*(x.^(2*i-1));
end
end

ret = ret*2/sqrt(pi);
```

Comment: Please detail the formulas you have been using.

Comment: Yes, I have used the taylor expansion series of error function given in this link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Taylor_series

Comment: Have a look at your values of $c$. They are wrong.

Comment: c =

   1.0000e+00
   3.3333e-01
   1.0000e-01
   2.3810e-02
   4.6296e-03
   7.5758e-04
   1.0684e-04
   1.3228e-05
   1.4589e-06
   1.4504e-07
   1.3123e-08
   1.0892e-09
   8.3507e-11
   5.9478e-12
   3.9554e-13
   2.4668e-14
   1.4483e-15
   8.0327e-17
   4.2214e-18
   2.1079e-19
   1.0025e-20
   4.5518e-22
   1.9771e-23
   8.2301e-25
   3.2893e-26
   1.2641e-27
   4.6785e-29

Comment: Here c(1) denotes the value to be multiplied with x, c(2) denotes the value to be multiplied with x^3 and so on.

Comment: The first few $c$'s actually look right, comparing them with the Wikipedia article. How bad is your error? This could very well just be catastrophic cancellation or similar.

Comment: erf(5) = 2.7884e+08 which is clearly wrong!

Comment: For $x=5$ your error bound (from the alternating series error estimate, not a Taylor error estimate) would be $\frac{5^{2n+3}}{n!(2n+3)}$. It takes a rather large $n$ to make that small, as you can see by running >> x=1:100;
>> y=5.^(2*x+3)./(factorial(x).*(2*x+3));
>> plot(x,y)

Comment: We get the bound of error in Taylor series as:
| E(b) | <= M * (b)^(n+1) / (n+1)!

Where M is the maximum value of erf(x) where x is from [-b,b].Taking b = 5
We know that in the range [-5,5] erf is a nondecreasing function. Thus M = erf(1)
M = 1.0
| E(b) | <= M * (b)^(n+1) / (n+1)!
| E(b) | <= 1.0  * (5)^(n+1) / (n+1)!  <= 10-9
1000000000 * (5)^(n+1)  <= (n+1)!
Thus for this inequality to satisfy n + 1 = 27
=> Thus n = 26

Comment: No, the Taylor error in Lagrange form needs to use successively higher derivatives in its bound, not erf itself. But even in the Taylor form, you are still waiting for $5^{2n}$ to compete with $n!$. Note that you do *not* have $5^{n}$ competing with $(n)!$ as you would with just ordinary $\exp$.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand your last comment.

Comment: Don't bother with the Lagrange error form. For a convergent, alternating series of terms which are decreasing in absolute value, the truncation error is less than the magnitude of the first neglected term. Eventually the series for erf has this property, though it takes longer for this to happen as $x$ gets larger.

Comment: Let's say it takes $m(x)$ terms in order for the terms to start decreasing in absolute value. (It will turn out that $m$ is something like $x^2$.) Then you want to include $\max \{ m(x),n(x)+1 \}$ terms where $n(x)$ is large enough that $\frac{|x|^{2n+3}}{(n+1)!(2n+3)}$ is smaller than your tolerance. If $x$ is moderately large, then $n$ must get pretty large for this to happen, because the numerator will grow faster than the denominator until $n$ gets moderately large.

Comment: I understand it now. However the question that I am provided with is I have to find number of terms in Taylor expansion such that absolute error in Taylor series is less than 10^(-9) for x in the range [-5,5]. For this I did that derivation. Source of the derivation is https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc/taylor-series-calc/v/error-or-remainder-of-a-taylor-polynomial-approximation

Comment: OK. Well, then you need to do your analysis over again, because that definitely doesn't happen with $n=26$. Perhaps your error was thinking that the behavior looks like $5^n/n!$ when in fact it looks like $5^{2n}/n!$; this occurs because the sequence of derivatives of erf at $x=0$ grows very rapidly with $n$ (specifically it behaves roughly like $\frac{(n)!}{((n-1)/2)!}$) when $n$ is odd).

Comment: @Ian Did you look at the video?

Comment: No, but looking at your work before I think you either forgot to include the factor of the derivative or you forgot that when you do include this factor, your numerator behaves mostly like $x^{2n} $ while your denominator behaves like $n!$. At any rate, in this problem the Lagrange error is cumbersomebecause it is tedious to get many derivatives of erf. Using the alternating series for your bound will simplify your task.

Comment: @Ian Thanks a lot buddy. You were absolutely right. I now figured it out and made the required changes in the program. It works absolutely fine.

Comment: I figured out for b=5 the value of n = 81 and for b = 3 the value of n is 37. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.